# Disable tasks from specific plugin (maven-publish) for specific subprojects in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like to disable all tasks which names start with 'publish' in Gradle. Something like

```
tasks.matching {
  it.name.startWith('publish') }.all {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:
I have a multi project build and I am using convention plugins like in this example provided (https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html). For the sake of keeping a clean structure I define **all** tasks in one convention plugin, which applies to **every** subproject.

Unfortunately I do not want all tasks to be available for every plugin. E. g. I do not want the tasks that come with maven-publish (publish, generatePomFileForMavenPublication, publishToMavenLocal...) in specific subprojects.

Comment: I propably named this question wrong. Better would be: Disable plugin for subproject...

Comment: Disabling tasks like this sounds difficult. It this an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you provide more context? What problem will selectively disabling publishing tasks solve?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I updated the question.

Comment: Using convention plugins is a good idea. Why do you only have one convention plugin though? I think it would help to split up the plugin into 'non-publishing conventions' and 'publishing conventions'. The 'publishing conventions' can also apply the 'non-publishing conventions' plugins, so you don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Of course I have more than one plugin, but I would like to keep the number of convention plugins as low as possible. I guess there is a tradeoff between usability and maintainability/readability I have to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I disabled all tasks in publishing-group.

```
// ugly workaround: disable all tasks that come with maven-publish plugin
tasks.matching { it.group == 'publishing' }.each {it.enabled = false}
```

I don't know if this counts as a solution, as there could be other tasks in publishing group which comes not from maven-publish.

Comment: This is reasonable. You could also filter by type `tasks.withType(AbstractPublishToMaven).each { it.enabled = false }`. The list of publishing tasks, and their types, is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks). You could also make the check conditional by [registering an input property](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:runtime_api_for_adhoc), and using [`onlyIf {}`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:skipping_tasks)